# grails XML to Object binding

Tags: java, xml, grails

Is there a grails plugin or library to do mapping from XML data into a Java class Object?

I'm looking for some groovy class that maps xml data to Java class fields.

---UPDATE-----

The below grails service class tries to do this mapping ,but it doesn't work.

Would someone give hints how to correct below code to make it work?

thanks

---

```
class DataBinderService {

boolean transactional = false
def grailsApplication
private BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl()

public List bindAllXmlData (Class targetClass, GPathResult source, List properties) {
    if (targetClass == null || source == null || properties == null) return null
    def resultList = []
    def  className = WordUtils.uncapitalize(targetClass.simpleName)
    source[className]?.each {
        def boundObj = bindXmlData(targetClass, it, properties)
        System.out.println(boundObj)
        resultList.add(boundObj)
    }
    return resultList
}

public Object bindXmlData (Class targetClass, GPathResult source, List properties) {
    if (targetClass == null || source == null || properties == null) return null
    def targetObject = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(targetClass.name).newInstance()
    if (targetObject) {
        return bindXmlData(targetObject, source, properties)
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

public Object bindXmlData (Object target, GPathResult source, List properties) {
    if (target == null || source == null || properties == null) return null
    wrapper.registerCustomEditor (Date.class, new CustomDateBinder())
    wrapper.setWrappedInstance(target)
    properties.each {String property ->
        if (property.contains('.')) {//This indicates a domain class to bind e.g. experiment.id -> Experiment
            def propertyName = property.tokenize('.')
            def id = source[propertyName[0]]["@${propertyName[1]}"]?.toString()
            if (id != null) {
                def subdomainInstance = null
                try {subdomainInstance = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("edu.kit.iism.experimentcenter.${WordUtils.capitalize(propertyName[0])}").get(id)} catch (Exception ex) {}
                if (subdomainInstance != null) wrapper.setPropertyValue(propertyName[0], subdomainInstance)
            }
        } else if (property.equals('id')) { //The id property is set as an attribute rather than text
            def id = source['@id']?.toString()
            if (id != null) wrapper.setPropertyValue(property, id)
        } else { //regular attributes
            def prop = source[property]?.toString()
            if (prop != null) wrapper.setPropertyValue(property, prop)
        }
    }
    return target
}
```

}

Comment: Groovy's `XMLSlurper` is not enough ?

Comment: it is not generic and general purpose. we need to manually parse the xml and save to Java object. right? what i need is a general method to automatically bind a java class with xml data

Comment: I have updated the OP. there is a class i try doing the binding. but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use Xstream for that. Check this article i wrote http://moskiteau.tumblr.com

Comment: this is really very good article. Exactly what i was looking for. I'll give a try for XStream. Thanks!